# can not save image in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

i have a problem, when i upload an image to Cloud Storage it returns me this error:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
}
}

im using expo with image pick to get the image from my device

```
const elegirImagen =async () => {
  let res = await imagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: imagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing:true,
    aspect:[4,3],
    quality:1,
  });

  if(!res.cancelled){
    const source = {uri:res.uri}
    console.log('imgage picker if',source)
    setImagen(source)
  }
}
```

this saves the image

```
 const uploadImage = async()=>{
  if(!imagen) return
  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };

  console.log('imagen uri upload', imagen.uri)
  const res = await fetch(imagen.uri);
  const blob = await res.blob();
  const filename = imagen.uri.substring(imagen.uri.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
  
  // Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `./images/${filename}` + filename);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob, metadata);
  
  // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
  uploadTask.on('state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      setProgreso(progress)
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case 'paused':
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case 'running':
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      // A full list of error codes is available at
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
      switch (error.code) {
        case 'storage/unauthorized':
          // User doesn't have permission to access the object
          break;
        case 'storage/canceled':
          // User canceled the upload
          break;
  
        // ...
  
        case 'storage/unknown':
          // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
          break;
        
      }
    },
    () => {
      // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      });
    }
  )}
```

and this uploads the image as firebase docs says but when i check de database i always get this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. the solution was to change the path in the database storage

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/` + filename);
```